# Retornar Array com nome de todos os arquivos em diretório

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, diretório, array

Preciso que minha página em HTML5 retorne um `Array` com todos os nomes e extensões de arquivos existentes em um diretório dentro do meu site. Consigo fazer isso em outras linguagens server-side, mas gostaria de fazê-lo em JS. há essa possibilidade?

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso somente com scripts client-side. Você pode fazer em JS server-side com o node.

Comment: hmm... que pena, estava querendo fazer isso sem precisar registrar links em JSON de cada imagem que estará na pasta. Sei que em Node.JS eu consigo, mas minha intenção é gastar tudo que tenha JS+HTML5 ao máximo, sem precisar do servidor...

Comment: É que só o servidor tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos do servidor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como já foi mencionado esta tarefa é dificil/impossivel do lado do cliente, linguagens do lado do servidor são a maneira correcta.

Mas, já que você pergunta, *e assumindo* que a directoria está no mesmo servidor e que a directoria tem um index com permissão via htaccess; então nesse index estão os ficheiros todos. Então, tendo essa página html com uma lista de links o jQuery já pode trabalhar.

Uma sugestão:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    context: document.body
}).done(function (data) {
    var allLinks = $(data).find('a');  
    var goodLinks = $.grep(allLinks, function (el) {
        return (el.pathname != '/'); 
    });
    var arrayFinal = [];
    $(goodLinks).each(function (i) {
        var objeto = {
            nome: this.pathname.split('.')[0],
            estencao: this.pathname.split('.')[1] || ''
        }
        arrayFinal.push(objeto);
    });
    console.log(goodLinks);
    console.log(arrayFinal[0]);
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q56j8/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Diretamente ***não*** é possível, pois javascript rodando numa página HTML é executado no navegador do *client* e não tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos do servidor, o que geralmente é uma questão séria de segurança.

Seria possível se seu servidor suportasse listagem de diretórios. Você poderia fazer o *parse* da página de listagem dos arquivos e recuperar os dados dos mesmos. Pesquisei um exemplo usando o Apache HTTP Server e encontrei [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://yoursite.com/images/",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("td > a").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
        alert("Found a file: " + $(this).attr("href"));
     });
  }
});
```

Mais uma vez, para reforçar, permitir listagens de arquivos pode ser um problema de segurança. Mas você poderia permitir isso para algumas pastas em específico.

Dependendo dos seus requisitos, seria melhor criar um serviço REST que retorne um JSON com a lista de arquivos necessários, assim você não fica nem "amarrado" a uma pasta específica.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível acessar o sistema de arquivos via JavaScript (no browser).

Já se estiver utilizando no lado do servidor com node.js [é possível](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

P.S.: Um possível *workaround* seria disponibilizar uma página que listasse esses arquivos do servidor para você e lhe retornasse de alguma forma (mas note que a listagem é feita do lado do servidor, que terá acesso ao sistema de arquivo).

Comment: Eu sei que consigo com Node.JS, minha inteção é usar 110% do JS+HTML5, por isso essa pergunta...

Comment: [Percebi](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/) ;) ...  o problema é que o "mundinho fechado" do browser vai te limitar em certos aspectos.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer isso com Node. Ai vai um exemplo simples. Crie uma pasta de nome qualquer e crie um arquivo chamado '`readdir.js`'; dentro desta pasta crie outra pasta com nome 'arquivos', dentro da pasta arquivos crie '`texto1.txt`', '`texto2.txt`' e '`texto3.txt`'.

```
// readdir.js 

var fs = require('fs');
var domain = require('domain').create();

fs.readdir('./arquivos',function(error,files){
   console.log(files);
});

domain.on("error",function(erros){
   console.log(erros);
});
```

> Saida: [ 'texto1.txt', 'texto2.txt', 'texto3.txt' ]

Acredito que seja isso que você deseja saber.