# Como obter o número de imagens em uma pasta com Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tentei utilizar esta função:

```
function getCount(foldername)
    {
      var myObject, f, filesCount;
      myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      f = myObject.GetFolder(foldername);
      filesCount = f.files.Count;
      document.write("The number of files in this folder is: " + filesCount);
    }
```

No entanto, obtenho o erro: *Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined*

Alguém sabe uma forma eficaz de obter o número total dos arquivos de imagens de uma pasta com `Javascript/Jquery`? Para facilitar, pode ser a contagem de tudo que há na pasta, pois não existe a possibilidade de haver outro tipo de arquivo que não seja de imagem.

Comment: Em que browser você está tentando executar isso?

Comment: O erro ocorre no chrome.

Comment: Vou arriscar dizer que não por Javascript ser uma linguagem client side, essas imagens que você quer contar vão estar no servidor (embora enquanto você está desenvolvendo ela esteja em um pasta no computador). Talvez seja possível com `ajax`, talvez...

Comment: Pois é...Percebi que Ajax seria a opção correta já que ele pode realizar request para um código beckend, mas como seria essa interação?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/493/retornar-array-com-nome-de-todos-os-arquivos-em-diret%C3%B3rio

Comment: ActiveX é um framework proprietário e funciona (mal) somente no Internet Explorer. Fique longe dela.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer com JavaScript client-side, pois o navegador não pode ter acesso aos arquivos do computador (exceto em situações específicas como upload de arquivos).

Se você precisa contar os arquivos no **client-side**, você pode fazer uma [extensão para o Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), sabendo que só vai funcionar nesse navegador.

Se você precisa contar os arquivos no servidor, precisará usar uma linguagem **server-side** como PHP, Python, Ruby, ou até mesmo o próprio JavaScript com node.js. Por exemplo, em PHP seria assim:

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator('/caminho/para/a/pasta');
echo "Quantidade de arquivos: " .iterator_count($fi);
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas será que é impossível mesmo com Ajax?

Comment: Se você estiver com a listagem de diretórios habilitada, é possível obter essa página via AJAX e contar os arquivos com JavaScript, conforme demonstrado na resposta linkada pelo @Maicon. No entanto, essa é uma prática desaconselhada por questões de segurança, já que você tornará público todos os conteúdos de uma pasta do servidor.